# Excel VBA Looping through activeX option buttons

Tags: vba, excel

A little background on my objective. I have a spreadsheet for risk assessments which needs to be automated, I'm using option buttons to give standard yes no options for a select number of cells which I've filtered and currently I'm running into two major problems.

First of which is a grouping of radio buttons and referencing that through code. With form controls I was able to just put them in a group box and give them all the same name ie. radYes and radNo but with activeX I can't use a group box to achieve this. This causes selection of one option button to remove the preset selection of another. I was able to bypass this by giving them all separate group names but now I cant use the name radYes/radNo in the different groups as it just references the first one.

This is my code for review:

```
Sub RadioController()

Dim total As Integer
Dim pass As Integer
Dim fail As Integer
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("C4:C8")

Dim o As Object

For Each cell In rng
    If Worksheets(2).radYes = True Then
        pass = pass + 1
        total = total + pass
    Else
        fail = fail + 1
    End If    
Next cell

Range("K4") = total


End Sub
```

Secondly, since this is meant to loop through a filtered group of cells. The macro keeps selecting the non visible cells and assigning a true value to the non-existent option buttons. I know this was long winded but I've researched all over on fixes to this and Stack Overflow seems to my best bet to getting some more knowledge on VBA.

Comment: Can you provide a snap shot of your sheet?

Answer (score 1):

- Radio Buttons (Option Button) are meant that you can only select one of them at a time. If you have independent Yes/No options, use CheckBoxes instead. Don't break standard GUI Look&Feel.
- It is a bad idea to give several objects the same name. You can loop over all objects like this.

  ```
  With ActiveSheet 
      For Each objX In .OLEObjects 
          Debug.Print "Name = " & objX.Name & "  Typ = " & TypeName(objX.Object)
      Next  
  End With
  ```
- To handle only visible cells, use

  ```
  For Each cell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  ```

  *Remark: Ask only **one question** per question. Stackoverflow is not only to help you but also others with the same or similar problem.*

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to show "Pass" or "Fail" (2 options) you only need one button for each assessment which is either TRUE or FALSE. However, you could also use 2 buttons, only one of which would be true. If you have many groups - regardless of whether each group consists of 1 buttons or 2 - you must set the `GroupName` property to another value for each one so that they operate independent from each other.
You can use the `LinkedCell` property to link each button to a cell, perhaps one which is hidden behind the button itself. This cell will hold the value TRUE or FALSE, depending upon the chosen option. You can let another, visible cell refer to the linked cell. Use a formula like this `= IF(A1, "Passed", "Failed")`. Presuming that A1 is the linked cell the cell with the formula will not show "Passed" or "Failed" depending upon the status of the option button.
For the purpose of counting, you can refer to the linked cells and count how many are TRUE. But you can also refer directly to the option buttons. The following code will count the number of Passes and Fails.

```
Private Sub CountButtons()

    Dim Btn As Shape
    Dim Pass As Long, Fail As Long

        For Each Btn In Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes
            With Btn
                If .Type = 12 Then
                    If Worksheets("Sheet2").OLEObjects(Btn.Name).Object Then
                        Pass = Pass + 1
                    Else
                        Fail = Fail + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next Btn
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an optimized code of the example from @funthomas. It prints only the name of  activeX option buttons, based on  [Excel Training VBA 2 Lesson 21 - Creating Controls at Runtime, On the Fly](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson21.htm)

```
With ActiveSheet 
    For Each objX In .OLEObjects
        If objX.progID = "Forms.OptionButton.1" then
            Debug.Print "Name = " & objX.Name & "  Typ = " & TypeName(objX.Object)
        End If 
    Next  
End With
```

Comment: why we should use objX.Object and we can't directly do typename(objX) ? can someone explain to me please ?

Comment: The answer is given in [OLEObjects object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobjects).
`You use the code name of a control in the names of its event procedures. However, when you return a control from the Shapes or OLEObjects collection for a sheet, you must use the shape name, not the code name, to refer to the control by name.`