# Excel displays buttons but says they don't exist

Tags: excel, vba

We have a spreadsheet that is used by a few dozen people, but one person today called up with an issue.

The error that is flagged is:

```
Sheet2.ButtonName.Caption = "new text here"
```

On my machine (and everyone else's), ButtonName is on Sheet2, it's correctly called ButtonName, and the code is running fine.

For this user, if you go to Sheet2, ButtonName is visible, but it's not clickable (nor are any of the other buttons), and Sheet2.Buttons.Count = 0?!?

Already confirmed that macros are running (and other chunks of code are running, so I know it's enabled). User also reports that she has this problem with other sheets.

How do I get a particular copy of Excel to recognize that buttons are a thing? (Excel 2013, if the version matters)

Comment: If you access them using `sheet2.buttonname` then it's an activex not Form control and isn't part of the `Buttons` collection. Are you sure that user doesn't have design mode on?

Comment: @Rory Good to know on Buttons collection. I remoted into her machine and couldn't get the buttons to respond in either design or live. Can't move them, can't copy, can't select - they're drawn on the screen but otherwise Excel doesn't want to admit they exist.

Comment: Can you loop through all the ActiveX controls on the worksheet and see what shows up that way? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45282180/4717755)

Comment: @peakpeak They tell me they've been trying for a few days, so hopefully a restart was part of that.

Comment: I suspect you're running into another update bug like this one: http://excelmatters.com/2014/12/10/office-update-breaks-activex-controls/ . Do you really need to use ActiveX instead of Form controls? The latter are much more stable.

Comment: @Rory I don't recall why our company was on ActiveX, but all the new stuff just uses pictures/shapes instead. (Probably for exactly this reason.)